# Is there a boolean version of `<` in Coq?

Tags: coq

Like `beq_nat` returns `bool` for eq comparison is there a corresponding thing for `<` or `<=`?

Comment: Yes, I think it is called `<?` , however I'm afraid I don't recall which module it is in as I use the one provided by `ssrnat`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are the fixpoint `leb` and the definition `ltb` [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Nat.html#leb). They can be abbreviated `<?` and `<=?`

EDIT: Reading ejgallego comment, they are defined in Coq.Init.Nat (so automatically loaded), but PeanoNat reexports the notations.